# How to add variables in a column as text using ggplot, facet_grid and geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, geom-text

consider the following tibble

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
df <-tibble(year = rep(1981:2020,4),
       x = rep(letters[1:8],20),
       y = rnorm(n = 160,0,1),
       group = rep(letters[10:13],40))
```

I want to plot a faceted grid based on variable `group` and as text in each panel, the years (`year`) corresponding to each group (`group`).

Below a failed attempt where years are overlapping and not correct

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) +
  geom_text(
    data = df,
    aes(
      x = x,
      y = 3,
      label = year,
      color = group
    ),
    alpha = 0.7,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  facet_grid( ~ group)
```

Thanks for support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want, but you can try the following

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) +
  geom_text(
    data = df,
    aes(
      x = x,
      y = 3,
      label = year,
      color = group
    ),
    alpha = 0.7,
    show.legend = FALSE,
    position = position_stack(vjust = 1.5), 
#    stat = "unique"
  ) +
  facet_grid( ~ group)
```

If you don't want the `year` to be repeated, uncomment the `stat = "unique"` line.

**UPDATE**
If you want a horizontal alignment you can create a new data frame

```r
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(x, group) %>% 
  summarise(year = str_c(unique(year), collapse=", "))

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) +
  geom_text(
    data = df2,
    aes(
      x = x,
      y = 1,
      label = year,
      color = group
    ),
    alpha = 0.7,
    show.legend = FALSE,
    position = position_stack(vjust = 1.5), 
    stat = "unique"
  ) +
  facet_grid( ~ group)
```

but with this alignment labels will overlap. You can try reducing the font-size or using `facet_wrap` to arrange the panels on two rows.

You can also manipulate strings in `df2` and add `"\n"` where you need it, but I think this cannot be easily adapted to every string.

Comment: ```geom_text(data = df, aes(x = 1,y = 3,label = year, color = group), alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = 1.5), stat = "unique") +
```
The following is one step in the right direction. Nevertheless, the years are still stacking vertically whereas I want them to be aligned horizontally... can you help with the last mile? thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope I understand your question correctly

Comment: Thanks that works. To avoid overlap, I just set x =5